# "Practical forms" of Chernoff bound for inequality in expectation

Tags: probability-theory, chernoff-bounds

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_multiplicative_form_of_Chernoff_bound_.28relative_error.29):

> The above formula is often unwieldy in practice, so the following looser but more convenient bounds are often used:
>
> (i) $Pr(X\geq (1+\delta)\mu)\leq e^{-\frac{\delta^2\mu}{3}}, 0<\delta<1$
>
> (ii) $Pr(X\leq (1-\delta)\mu)\leq e^{-\frac{\delta^2\mu}{2}}, 0<\delta<1$

The assumption they use is $E[X]=\mu$.

Would (i) still hold if we only assume $E[X]\leq \mu$? Would (ii) still hold if we only assume $E[X]\geq\mu$?

If not, what "practical forms" do we have in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more practical just because it has

> the advantage of being easier to state and compute with in many situations (quoted from [1]).

---

I am not sure whether (i) still holds for $\mu' = E[X] \le \mu$. At least, we cannot obtain that directly from the following computation:

$$Pr[X \ge (1 + \delta) \mu] \le Pr[X \ge (1 + \delta) \mu'] \le e^{-\frac{\delta^2 \mu'}{3}} \ge e^{-\frac{\delta^2 \mu}{3}}$$

---

[1] Mitzenmacher, Michael and Upfal, Eli (2005). Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis. Cambridge University Press. ISBN 0-521-83540-2.

Comment: You can check what happens in some case where the large deviation behavior is known exactly, say the binomial distribution.